# How to keep checking a value until it changes without using infinite loop?

Tags: objective-c, infinite-loop, observer-pattern, key-value-observing

My code needs to check on a sensor value until it becomes 1 or the code reach the time out. Hence I am thinking of such an infinite loop.

The `sensor` is a singleton object that has access to sensor value at real-time. The default value is 0 and I want to monitor for the value change to 1.

```
for (;;) {
  int sensorVal = [sensor getVal];
  if (sensorVal == 1) break;
  if (timeout) break;
}
```

But the problem is that I don't want to have an infinite loop in my code. I am wondering if there is a better way to write this in Objective-C?

Comment: Use KVO or notifications.

Comment: or a `NSTimer` for periodic polling.

Comment: What's really `[sensor val]`? How do you get it? Do you need a delegate method? A block completion?

Comment: @Lame It's a singleton object that can access the sensor value at real-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with using the **KVO** (key Value observation).

Observe for changes that you want:

```
[sensor addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"val" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];//observing the key in this class
```

Then use this delegate method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"val"]) {
        /* Do the work here */
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the value is not a property but a function that returns the value? Can I still use the KVO?